# .Net: How to use a WPF user control in a windows forms application?

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-controls

How to use a WPF user control in a windows forms application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put WPF control into a Windows Forms Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053501/put-wpf-control-into-a-windows-forms-form)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the MSDN:

> Use the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(VS.85).aspx) control to place a
>   WPF UIElement on your Windows Forms
>   control or form.

Example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the ElementHost control for hosting the
    // WPF UserControl.
    ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
    host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    // Create the WPF UserControl.
    HostingWpfUserControlInWf.UserControl1 uc =
        new HostingWpfUserControlInWf.UserControl1();

    // Assign the WPF UserControl to the ElementHost control's
    // Child property.
    host.Child = uc;

    // Add the ElementHost control to the form's
    // collection of child controls.
    this.Controls.Add(host);
}
```

[Here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms) is a nice tutorial how to do that.

> The control called ElementHost is for
>   WPF in WinForms what the
>   WindowsFormsHost was for WinForms in
>   WPF. In the designer, you can find
>   this control in the Toolbox underneath
>   "WPF Interoperability".