# Put WPF control into a Windows Forms Form?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

How do you put a WPF control into a Windows Forms `Form`? Most likely I will be inserting my WPF control into a `Windows.Forms.Panel`.

Comment: Dupe of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865567/net-how-to-use-a-wpf-user-control-in-a-windows-forms-application

Comment: Another: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685142/mixing-wpf-with-a-winform-application

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Put an  [**`ElementHost`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control inside the panel. This control can then host a WPF element. From the WinForms designer, you can find this control under 'WPF Interoperability'. First  you may need to add `WindowsFormsIntegration.dll` to your project's references.

For an example, see [Walkthrough: Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-a-wpf-composite-control-in-windows-forms).

Comment: could you provide a short example..?

Comment: Will this WPF Control in WinForms Application use Direct X?

Answer (score 4):

Try to read this:

Hosting a WPF Control in a Windows Forms Application

http://community.infragistics.com/wpf/articles/hosting-a-wpf-control-in-a-windows-forms-application.aspx

First add references to the WPF namespaces (PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, UIAutomationProvider, UIAutomationTypes, and WindowsBase). Next create an instance of the ElementHost control and the control you wish to embed in the Windows Forms application and then hook that control up to the ElementHost control. Then simply add the ElementHost control to your Forms control collection:

```
    ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
    System.Windows.Controls.ListBox wpfListBox = new System.Windows.Controls.ListBox();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    wpfListBox.Items.Add("Item " + i.ToString());
    }
    host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    host.Controls.Add(wpfListBox);
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(host);
```

However, if you want to use `XAML` to describe the WPF control that you want to use in the Windows Forms application, you would need to add an Avalon UserControl item to your project. This will create a `UserControl1.xaml` file and a `UserControl1.xaml.cs` file. You can then modify the UserControl1.xaml file to contain whatever XAML you wish to describe your control. Then you would simply create an instance of this control and add it to the

```
ElementHost control as in the above example:
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
host.Controls.Add(uc1);
host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.panel1.Controls.Add(host);
```

In addition, you will need to modify the project file because the Windows Application does not what to do with the XAML file. You will need to open the project file (.csproj, .vbproj, etc.) in an editor like Notepad and then scroll to the bottom. You will see the following line:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

You will need to copy this line and paste it just below the above line and then change "CSharp" to "WinFX" so that the two lines look like:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.WinFx.targets" />
```

Now save this file and reload the project using VS and run the application.

Source: http://windowsclient.net/learn/integration.aspx

Comment: Avalon... that is a long time ago... I almost forgot

Comment: Actually the host.Controls is a System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection. Use host.Child = wpfControl for importing a wpf control in windows forms.

Comment: What do you mean by "add references to the WPF namespaces"? Are those actually the names of specific DLLs which should be referenced?

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the above answers for quick reference:

if you don't want to mess with editing the project and want to stick with the designer:

be sure to add reference for `WindowsFormsIntegration.dll` which is normally from window's \reference assemblies\microsoft\Framework...

and if you are using a wpf usercontrol in your solution, you probably already got references to

System.Windows.Presentation,System.Windows.Activities, 
System.Windows.CompnentModel, System.Windows..RunTime, System.Windows.WorkFlowServices, System.Xaml.

otherwise be sure to add the required foregoing references.

in a windows form member you add  the wpf usercontrol myWpfUsrCtl to the windows form as follows

```
void addWpfUsrCntl()
{
    var elemthost1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost();

    elemthost1.Dock = DockStyle.None; // change to to suit your need

     // you can add the WPF control to the form or any other desired control
    elemthost1.Parent = this;

    //elemthost1.AutoSize = true; // change to to suit your need

    ... // change to to suit your need

    elemthost1.Child = myWpfUsrCtl; // Assign the WPF control
}
```

Comment: What is `FinCurl_` in the example?