# How to show WPF window in the winform applciation

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

How to show WPF window in the winform applciation? Can I just use Windows1 win = new Windows1(); win.show()?

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/jdanforth/open-a-wpf-window-from-winforms) explains the following answer in detail.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;

var wpfwindow = new WPFWindow.Window1();
ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfwindow);
wpfwindow.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

uh, odd this was not anwered...Personally, I use **ElementHost** to achieve that.

Here is a detailled example : 
[Put WPF control into a Windows Forms Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053501/put-wpf-control-into-a-windows-forms-form)

For example, we have an old WinForm application with tons of WinForm forms. However, every new Windows developped are done in WPF.

To be able to show every new WPF forms :

1. we have a main winForm Form which have a big ElementHost on it [only that]
2. Then, when I want to show a WPF windows,  I do a call similar to that :

---

```
//create the winform Hoster, which contains a ElementHost on it
form_MyWPF_Hoster MyForm = new form_MyWPF_Hoster();

//Create the instance of your WPF control
form_WPFNewWindows MyWPF = new form_WPFNewWindows();

//Add the WPF control to the elementHost  (it is publicly accessible...i know, it's bad..)
MyForm.elementHost1.child = MyWPF ;    

//show the WinForm : 
MyForm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: It was answered, but was recently deleted by a mod because the posted answer only provided links with no explanation.

Comment: The links in the deleted answer had all expired, rendering the answer useless.