# C# Win Form Spell Checker .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, winforms, spell-checking

I'm looking to implement a spell checker on my win form app. The app need to be built in .Net 3.5 and I'm struggling to figure out what I need to do. I walked through an example of importing a Windows Presentation Form control that did this perfectly, but that control is only available in .Net 4 Framework.

Can anybody point me in the right direction on this please? I'm only using this control for the one richTextBox, so i dont want to spend too much time on this one element of my project.

Thanks

Comment: Its for a Win Form, i need to spell check the richTextBox as its being edited.

Comment: I removed the tags, indicating your working with wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a TextBox to your form
2. In the XAML tab, add the following code between TextBox tags:

   `SpellCheck.IsEnabled = "True"`

You can add the same code in the standard C# code window. Just enter:

```
textBox1.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
```

3.Now, launch the application.

If you enter incorrect words, these are underlined in red. If you right-click the word, you get some spelling suggestions to correct.

I hope, thats what u wanted.

Comment: XAML Tab? Whis is on a Windows Form App?

Comment: I thought ur working with WPF, because you added "WPF" in your tags

Comment: Sorry, I added it my tags as I'm looking to add a WPF control to my Win App. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053501/put-wpf-control-into-a-windows-forms-form , u could add a wpf control to your winforms, with the integrated spellchecker, which wpf enables you.. it might work.

Answer (score 1):

Hope these links may help you

http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2010/02/spell-check-enable-your-winform.html
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5277/NetSpell-Spell-Checker-for-NET