# Encoded information being displaying in Data Grid View not displaying correctly in Rich Text Box

Tags: vb.net, utf-8

I've got some German character that I am displaying in a Vb.net Data Grid View.

[image: DGV Data]

But when I assign it to a Rich Text Box.  The data is not displayed properly.

```
rtbComposition.Text = dgvAddresses.Item("address", 0).Value
```

It looks like this in the RTB.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: It's all about encoding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591369/breaks-encoding-in-richtextbox

Comment: @sparkysword How do I select/access RTB V5?  There is some code there, but I don't know where to put it?

Comment: Create a class with that name (RichText50W) and declare that type when you dynamically add a richtextbox. i.e. Dim newBox as Richtext50W. This is not the only solution though to your problem if that doesn't work for you. This comes with some problems with hyperlinks (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039967/strange-shift-when-selecting-text-in-richtext-box-v5-that-contains-hyperlinks) but you can also try using value.tostring, or get a different type of text editor/control that has higher encoding spectrum to work with. Try it out, and see what works for you.

Comment: (code goes into class called richtextbox50w)