# how to make a vertical progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a vertical progress bar and I understand that there isn't any easy way to do it.

I've seen this code floating around the forums:

```
public class VerticalProgressBar : ProgressBar
{ 
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams; 
            cp.Style |= 0x04; 
            return cp; 
        } 
     } 
 }
```

My question is where do I put this code? Does it go in my program.cs file or the form that the progress bar is on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter where you put the code, you only have to make sure you are creating a `VerticalProgressBar` in your Form.Designer.cs file.

You have to change

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar1
```

to

```
private VerticalProgressBar progressBar1
```

(or whatever it is called) and

```
this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
```

to

```
this.progressBar1 = new VerticalProgressBar();
```

Comment: VerticalProgressBar doesnt seem to work at all, do i need a specific namespace for it?

Comment: It should be in the same namespace as your form is. Just put the code underneath the `partial class Form1` in the Form1.Designer.cs

Comment: No such thing as VerticaProgressbar in Windows Forms. It's not listed under Visual Studio Object Browser

Answer (score 2):

Still don't have this control available in VS 2022 so I used a TablePanelLayout with one column and two rows. and just changed the RowStyle SizeType percent.  You can easily add code to change the panel color when a limit is reached etc.

```
   public class BarGraph : Panel
   {
       private Panel panel1;
       private Panel panel2;
       private TableLayoutPanel table;
       private float percentValue;

       public BarGraph()
       {
           table = new TableLayoutPanel();
           table.ColumnCount = 1;
           table.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
           table.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
           table.RowCount = 2;
           table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
           table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
           table.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
           table.Margin = new Padding(0);
           table.Padding = new Padding(0);
           table.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.None;

           panel1 = new Panel();
           panel2 = new Panel();

           panel1.AutoSize = false;
           panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
           panel1.Padding = new Padding(0);
           panel1.Margin = new Padding(0);
           panel2.AutoSize = false;
           panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
           panel2.Padding = new Padding(0);
           panel2.Margin = new Padding(0);

           panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
           panel2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

           table.Controls.Add(panel1, 0, 0);
           table.Controls.Add(panel2, 0, 1);

           this.Controls.Add(table);
           this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 500);
           
           SetValue("50");
       }
       public float GetValue()
       {
           return this.percentValue;
       }
       public void IncreaseValue()
       {
           IncrementValue(percentValue - 1);
       }
       public void DecreaseValue()
       {
           IncrementValue(percentValue + 1);
       }
       private void IncrementValue(float value)
       {
           SetValue(value.ToString());
       }
       public void SetValue(string value)
       {
           float.TryParse(value, out percentValue);
           if ((percentValue >= 0) && (percentValue <=100))
           {
               table.RowStyles.RemoveAt(1);
               table.RowStyles.RemoveAt(0);
               table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100 - percentValue));
               table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, percentValue));
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a brand new application, use WPF. vertical progress bars are built-in

```
<ProgressBar Orientation="Vertical" />
```

Comment: ah no its a large project i'm creating just doing my final form :\

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053501/put-wpf-control-into-a-windows-forms-form

Comment: So you recommend adding the whole WPF libraries instead of adding 5 lines of WinForms code and keep the project clean ?

Comment: I was trying to contribute to a conversation. I don't understand what you're doing. Since when did adding a library references such an ungodly thing? Are we still coding on 8086? Define keeping project clean. Interop is not new, and it won't "mess" things up if you use it right. After all .NET is interop for Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while looking for a way to make a vertical progress bar and used code in the *question* as the *answer* to my own problem. The *accepted* is right for sure so ✔ and ✔.

I'm adding this as just a bit of added value hopefully. In my own project I also needed to customize the color. I ended up using the OP's *question* to make my class and modified it so that `ForeColor` can be set to change the indicator color. All this and a working sample to boot.

```
class VerticalProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public VerticalProgressBar() => SetWindowTheme(Handle, string.Empty, string.Empty);
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        { 
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= 0x04;
            return cp;
        }
    }
    [DllImport("uxtheme", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public extern static Int32 SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd,
                  String textSubAppName, String textSubIdList);
}
```

---

[image: example]

---

**Designer code**

*"Where to put the code" (as stated in the accepted answer).*

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.progressBarTemperature = new weather_client.VerticalProgressBar();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    .
    .
    .
    // 
    // progressBarTemperature
    // 
    this.progressBarTemperature.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 12);
    this.progressBarTemperature.Name = "progressBarTemperature";
    this.progressBarTemperature.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 113);
    this.progressBarTemperature.TabIndex = 2;
    // 
    // MainForm
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(10F, 25F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(385, 144);
    this.Controls.Add(this.progressBarTemperature);
    .
    .
    .
    this.Name = "MainForm";
    this.Text = "Main Form";
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
private VerticalProgressBar progressBarTemperature;
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/weather-client-data-bindings.git) this sample.

Answer (score 0):

The code above for adding some VerticalProgressBars works fine, but I couldn't update a specific value in runtime...
If I change the values in the normal settings, it works, but I have to change them in runtime.

This doesn't work:

```
foreach (VerticalProgressBar _vb in fehlerBars)
{
    _vb.Minimum = 0;
    _vb.Maximum = 100;
    _vb.SetState(2); //Red
    _vb.Value = 23;
    _vb.Update();
    _vb.Refresh();
}
```