# Drawing real time 2D graphics using WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d

A table called floorLayout has the original cordinates of the objects stored. These details are showed in a 2D picturebox with basic 2D shapes.
       A slave of above table gets updated real time for new cordinates of the objects and these new locations should be also udpated into the 2D shapes (by changing colour, location etc).

I am certainly new to graphics. So following are couple of questions I would like to clarify.

1. Do I need a backgroundworker with a thread to handle updates to 2D graphics?
2. Is there any other approach for this scenario?

Edit after helpful comments:

There's a table with a basic seating plan details. 
Seat Number, Seat Type (represented by an eclipse or a square), Original Seat Location

When a seat is occupied or reserved, the reference shape in the picture box colour must be changed.

Seats can be in different sections. However at times a certain seat can be coupled with another seat. When a seat is coupled with another, its current location becomes the location of its couple seat (location remain original). Both seats' colour changes.

When decouple, the secondary seat location changes back to its original location and colour changes.

It means for each DML transaction that seating lsyout has an impact. Thats what I want to manage without compromising performance.

The application has three parts. Set up (login is a part of set up), Seating allocation, Graphical layout. Although it is in C#, the model is in 3-tier layered architecture for future web extensibility (if required). Plus having services and data access separately gives lots of freedom n easy to manage.

Given this scenario what're my options?

**Edit2:**[2014/07/01]

While trying out the Bitmap based drawing for my original question, I have come across an issue related to my threading. I am posting here, as it's infact related to the discussion I had with the capable answerers.

```
    public void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs d)
    {
        //insert seats (sql call via service/access interaces) to table
         AddSeats();
    }

    //this doesn't get fired----<<<-------
    public void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs p)
    {
        txtFlag.Text = p.ProgressPercentage.ToString();

    }

    //this works fine
    public void bgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs r)
    {
        if (r.Cancelled)
        {
            txtFlag.Text = "Failed";
        }
        else
        {
            //load datagridview using datatable returned by select query
            GetSeats();
            //draw the bitmap with a loop over the datagridview  
            DrawFuntion();

            //bgWorker.ReportProgress(prog, txtFlag.Text);
        }
    }
```

One major issue: 
 1. does this really make sense that I use bgworker to do the insertion to database, when it's completed I am calling loadgridview and draw methods?
 2. I infact think, it's best to call draw method within bgworker, but I can't figure out how (logically, and functional flow-wise)
 3. When I tried to run DrawFunction() within DoWork(), it just threw the biggest cross thread error: that access to UI controls in the form which are created using a different thread is not allowed.

How can I make sense of this?

Comment: how do u update the shapes? with mouse actions or a trigger from somewhere else?

Comment: Shapes get the update call from an event trigger. Infact bunch of event triggers like Add a new object, Update object, Delete object.

Comment: In such a situation , I would use an abstract class shape , and all shapes inherit from it(each has its own properties). You either add an event to the basic shape which is assigned to your table to update it but it's a waste of memory because of the lots of events u have. or create a handler that handles the shapes u have in program ( the controller of all shapes which add,remove or update) in this class u'll store the list of shapes u have and this class will call the update function.. Is that close to ur problem ?

Comment: Just to verify, you meant it's not viable to draw a new shape each time "Add" event is called and it's not good to update the existing item when "Update" event is called? Further I have an issue of maintaining created items in the memory - so I could refer and update them.

Comment: If the drawing of the plan is rather involved, a BackgroundWorker thread may indeed help. As it can't draw on the UI itself, it could create and(or update a Bitmap and inform the UI thread when a new version is ready to display.  For better guidance you may want oto throw a few numbers at us: how many shapes, how ofter do they change?

Comment: @TaW I have updated the post with relevant info.

Comment: @SaraS. If using ready made images can *ease* the process than drawing, I am open it too.

Comment: what about having a Seat Class that contains properties of (original color,original location,coupled color,coupled location) and methods of (set color: sets the origianl color // set location://sets the original location// set coupling information:fills the coupling color and location// remove coupling information//remove the coupling and restore the original info). and a Draw function that takes (Grahics g) in this function u can draw the shape

Comment: so now who will call the draw function of the shape? that's what i meant by the controller ,this class receives the events of updates and passes it to the corresponding shape and for loop over the shapes to draw them. in the paint event of the control u draw on.

Comment: Is the location the x,y of the shape or it's just the row of the seat ?

Comment: @SaraS. I am using `Point` in C# to get and set location. SqL Server side it is `geometry`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56539/discussion-between-boncodigo-and-sara-s).

Comment: `Given this scenario what're my options?` - You can keep struggling and fighting against winforms incapabilities, or you could switch you current, relevant .Net [Windows UI technology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can achieve this in a few lines of code using proper DataBinding.

Comment: @HighCore entire programme's backend is already in place - using WinForms. Only this Graphic bit (well lot) is pending and yes I am struggling. One question, can I integrate Graphics from WPF with my existing application? `Few Lines Of code` is indeed attractive...

Comment: @bonCodigo yes, you can integrate WPF content in an existing winforms application really easily by using the [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx) winforms control. See [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5053518/643085)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the layout I would go for, considering the results of our chat:

Given the time constraint of the current project, keep it in Winforms, but keep WPF in mind for a future revision.

Drawing a thousand seats is not a big problem, but in order to keep the GUI responsive it should be done by a background worker like this:

Create two `Bitmap` properties:

```
public Bitmap bmp_Display { get; set; }
public Bitmap bmp_Buffer { get; set; }
```

In the display Panel's `Paint` event you simply dump the bmp_Display onto the panel like this:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp_Display,  Point.Empty);
```

This is a single command and will happen real fast.

To create the updated floorplan the background thread draws the seats onto the bmp_Buffer, maybe like this:

```
 foreach (Seat s in SeatList)
 {
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(seatBrushes[s.State], 
                             new Rectangle(s.Location, s.Size);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s.Name, seatFont, Brushes.Black, s.Location);                        
 }
```

When it is done, it dumps it onto the bmp_Display like this:

```
bmp_Display = (Bitmap)bmp_Buffer.Clone();
```

To do that you should assure thread safety, maybe by a lock.

Finally the display Panel is `invalidated`.

The details will depend on the data structure and the business logic you will be using.  If you will transfer only the changes, use them to update the data structure and still draw them all. You can Initialize the buffer `Bitmap` with a nice image of the floorplan with the tables and other things.

If needed you can create a helper app to act as a floorplan editor which would create the seats data structure and map it to the floorplan coordinates of the seats.

Here is an example of how the background worker can update the bitmap. Note that the error handling is practically non-existent; also only one of the locks should be necessary. And you need to get at the data somehow. The Seat class is just a dummy, too.

```
List<SolidBrush> seatBrushes = new List<SolidBrush>() 
    { (SolidBrush)Brushes.Red, (SolidBrush)Brushes.Green  /*..*/ };

public Bitmap bmp_Display { get; set; }
public Bitmap bmp_Buffer { get; set; }

public class Seat  
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int State { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; } 
    //...
}

private void drawFloorplan(List<Seat> seats)
{
    Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp_Buffer);
    Font sFont = new Font("Consolas", 8f);
    Size seatSize = new Size(32, 20);
    foreach (Seat s in seats)
    {
        G.FillRectangle(seatBrushes[s.State], new Rectangle(s.Location, seatSize));
        G.DrawString(s.Name, sFont, Brushes.Black, s.Location);
    }
    G.Dispose();
    sFont.Dispose();


}

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // get the seat data..
            List<Seat> seats = new List<Seat>();

            if (seats.Count > 0)
            {
                drawFloorplan(seats);
                try { bmp_Display = (Bitmap)bmp_Buffer.Clone(); } 
                catch { /*!!just for testing!!*/ }
                //lock(bmp_Display) { bmp = (Bitmap) bmp_Buffer.Clone(); }
            }

        }
    }

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Cancelled == true))
    { this.tbProgress.Text += "Cancelled!"; }
    else if (!(e.Error == null))
    { this.tbProgress.Text += ("Error: " + e.Error.Message); }
    else
    { panel1.Invalidate(); }
}


private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    try { e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, Point.Empty); } catch {/*!!just for testing!!*/ }
    //lock (bmp){   e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, Point.Empty);    }

}
```

**Edit 2** A few words about thread safety: The point of TS is to ensure that no two threads try to access the same object at the same time. Looking at the code one could wonder how it could happen, since it is only upon its completion that the BW thread will trigger the Invalidate. However things are more complicated with threads. **They always are!**  Here for example the problems will come in when the system intself triggers an invalidate at a time the BW thread is dumping its result into the display bitmap. (The system is free to do so, whenever it sees a reason to get the screen updated.)

To avoid this one of the concurring threads should block its access while it is working with the resource. I suggest the do_Work method. Chances are that you never encounter a problem in your tests. My testbed ran up to 30 times per second (!) and after a few minutes it did. The `try - catch` only prevents crashing. For production code the whole situation should be avoided by using a `lock`.

Careful with `lock` though: 'lock blocks' and can create deadlocks, when used too generously..

Comment: Just saw your message. Thanks for the input :) Let me upload a code snippet I have as well. It's like BackGroundWorker is hitting a blind wall at the moment - specially with error handling & updating progress. It's just fire `ProgressChanged()` Event . [This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners) is great and confusing - specially for using Thread.Sleep(). Are we really supposed to poke UI thread when using BGWorker? Speak to you soon. **And Germany won yesterday!**

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep()` is only to create a long running task. You won't need or want that. And no need for progress reports either as the paint job will be done in a fraction of a second. You only need to signal the completion. Yes, we won. But the match was horrible. Painful. Nerve-wrecking. In other words: it was great!

Comment: You will also want to take a look at the example code in MSDN: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywkkz4s1.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I just posted this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510531/does-it-mean-that-invoke-method-has-to-be-called-on-each-ui-control). Exactly the same goes, when I call upon DrawFunction() which invokes on picturebox control...

Comment: WRT to the second question: If you followed some posts about the bw-thread updating the UI: all those invokes miss the point. The only interaction is in assigning the bitmap clone, which is __not__ part of the UI! But since the display clone will be use in the paint event there could be a concurrency problem, which the lock should prevent.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just noticed that the 2nd question is about the DGV. Well, Luaan gave good advice. You can do all the DB stuff in the bw and only communicate the Datasource, probably like using the Bitmap buffer for the graphics.. I haven't done that myself yet, though, so I can't help you here.

Comment: With regards to your `WRT` comment. Looking at my edit in this question, is my current execution flow correct? Insert within `DoWork`, then after it's completed, I do the select and drawing (bitmap)? I just can't figure out how I can run drawing method withing `DoWork`. How would you align this if you were to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56598/discussion-between-taw-and-boncodigo).

Comment: Alright saw thr updated answer. Thanks much again. **Drawing a thousand seats is not a big problem, but in order to keep the GUI responsive it should be done by a background worker** . For that + thread-safety. Learnt much :)

Comment: Good, there are a few remarks in the chat; did you notice?

Comment: I am not sure about the `locks` you had mentioned though.

Comment: See my note at the end of the post!

Comment: I just wanted to refer to our chat - but it keeps saying the page is not found. What went wrong? There was quite great insights there... and I am having issues at the moment with the code-expanding anyway.

Comment: Hm ,that's strange indeed. Did out chat no have [enough posts maybe](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention). I had no idea that was important!

Comment: holly... that means whitboard has been deleted? what on earth going on? Ofcourse the chat had important elements and I regret for not copying it down. Don't look at me like "wth" haha. But I do refer to anything - in time to contemplate and re-evaluate...

Comment: No, I meant I didn't know that having at least __15 posts__ in the chat was so important! That's what the link I wrote seems to say. Down at the bottom. After assuring us at the top that the chat posts were persistent. Duh..! - Well If you have fresh questions, shoot and if you want to open a chat room, it'll be fine by me..

Comment: Neither did I... this is pure loss... :D Sure let me get the memory wired up with current issue.

Comment: How are things? Well we are required to do a feature adding to the app. So called version 2. Do you have any idea what sort of a shape/control is used in cinema/airline booking forms to represent seats? Our client wants to have a click and book feature. I am foreseeing that this feature may reduce the `painting` load on the app. What do you think? (And apologies if I am talking as if that you remember this question ;))

Comment: One of main questions we have is, do we always have to customize floor layout set up for each of the different customers? I am guessing other seating/floor layout scheduling systems are quite dynamic.

Comment: Hi, you're right, I don't remember much of that problem. It is about restaurants, right? It is in production now? Are you drawing the floorplan all in gdi+ now or are there controls for the items? How many tables and how many seats will there be? how do you configure the flooplan now? In a file oe a database? or is in all in code? And I guess we should move to chat asap.. you may want to invite me..

Comment: I created a site, but I am not seeing the link here to invite you for chat room. It's 2D Graphics, I have added you there.

Comment: To get back to your first question: Making a drawn map clickable is not hard, if the drawn items are either rectangles or if clicking their bounding rectangle is good enough. simply do a check for each of it an your itemslist: foreach (planItem pItem in thePlanList)  { if (pItem .theBoundingRect.Contains(e.Location))   {  //... do things with the clicked item    } } - So I wouldn't use controls like panels or labels at all. - As for the other question: I would write a floorplan editor, both to make your life easier and, maybe, to offer it to customers. for a surcharge, of course..