# Does it mean that Invoke() method has to be called on each UI control?

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

Following is a method that does `Insert` into the database table. And I am calling this method within `DoWork()` of BackGroundWorker thread. It obviously throws me the "cross thread operation not valid..." error. As I understand, I could use `Invoke()` method on UI controls if those to be accessed within `DoWork()`. BUT does it mean each of the following UI controls should have to be *invoked*? Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
    private void AddToOccupations()
    {
        if (dataGridViewSearch.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow datarow in dataGridViewSearch.SelectedRows)
            {
                try
                {
                    AllocationModel occupation = new AllocationModel()
                    {
                        User_ID = userID,
                        Merge_Status = (int)((MergeStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(MergeStatus), cmbMergeStatus.SelectedItem.ToString())),
                        Start_Date = dateTimePickerFROMDate.Value,
                        Seat_Type = datarow.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                        Occupation_Status = cmbStatus_Type.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                        Session = datarow.Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                        Seat_Number = (Int32)datarow.Cells[0].Value,
                        Number_of_Guests = (Int32)datarow.Cells[1].Value
                    };

                    // Call the service method 
                    var success = this.allocationService.AddToOccupation(occupation);

                    if (success)
                    {
                        // display the message box
                        MessageBox.Show(
                            Resources.Add_Occupation_Success_Message,
                            Resources.Add_Occupation_Success_Title,
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                        // Reset the screen
                        //this.Reset();

                        DoCurrentFreeSearch();
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("No Records Inserted!");
                }
                catch (FormatException ex)
                {
                    errorMessage = "Insert Error: \n";
                    errorMessage += ex.Message;
                    MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Warning! No Row is selected...");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer to your title question is: Yes.

If a background worker thread needs to access a UI item it can only do so by `Invoking` a method of it.

The problem of putting data into a DGV from a BW is best addressed by accessing its DataSource in a de-coupled way. I just did a little test to see if my suggestion from the original post works and it looks fine.

So, like with the Bitmap, you can create two `DataSources` as Properties; one to fill from the background worker and one to use as the DGV's `Datasource`.

```
public List<SeatData> theSeats_buffer { get; set; }
public List<SeatData> theSeats_DS { get; set; }
```

In the BW thread DoWork() you fill the `theSeats_buffer` list by calling an appropriate function void or bool getSeatData() and when you are done with the workload you pass the data into the `theSeats_DS`, maybe like this:

```
theSeats_DS= new List<Cols>(); theSeats_DS.AddRange(theSeats_buffer);
```

Again, this operation must be made thread-safe, probably by locking the receiving list `theSeats_DS`.

since the `DataSource` has been re-created it should be re-assigned in the `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` event; I did it right along with invalidating the display panel1:

```
private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Cancelled == true))
    { this.tbProgress.Text += "Cancelled!";    }
    else if (!(e.Error == null))
    {  this.tbProgress.Text += ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);    }
    else
    { panel1.Invalidate(); DGV.DataSource = theSeats_DS; }
}
```

With regard to the DB Inserts, I don't know how it relates. This answer is only about getting data from somewhere asynchrously and sending them to the UI.

Getting data from the DGV into the database is not something that would happen in the BW thread though, at least not the one that gets triggered upon incoming changes. If you use the DGV for input, concurrency will be an issue!! It is bad enough, if the seat one tries to reserve is actually taken by the time you press enter. But that can't be prevented. However, you need to ensure that the input isn't wiped out by incoming changes.. OTOH, a signal would be nice..

Concurrency is tricky!

Answer (score 2):

You should separate the worker code from the GUI code. Don't you have a `DataSource` on that data grid? You should basically first get the data you need from the grid (the selected rows) and pass them to the background worker from the GUI code (the button click or whatever). You can then report the work progress through `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` (which executes the progress event on the GUI thread).

If you can't decouple the GUI code from the worker code completely, you'll have to use `Invoke`s for the rest. However, it's not clear from your code why you would need that, `ReportProgress` should be quite enough.

Comment: Here's the functional flow: Add Button Click --> Verifications of Method Delegates (as there are other types of inserts) --> Input Validations --> Respective DML method call (e.g. this AddToOccupations()) Since you pointed out the need for separation, I guess at Input Validation Level, I shall create a class to hold the GUI input data. Then call that object's properties to pass the values here.

Answer (score -1):

Since the controls run on the UI thread, and not on the background worker thread, all of their functions need to be invoked.

Comment: So that's the obvious I am facing. If I am to change the above method (number of DML transaction based methods) that's going to be a huge change in the codes...what do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: If you can use C#5 for your work, then this would be an ideal candidate for the async/await feature. It is much less intrusive in your code.

Comment: @Emile darn as it is, I am on 4.0 and it's not going to go uphill anytime soon...And now I see **WHY** Asynch/Await *made their debut*...Care enough to provide me an example that you recommend(on the web) for Asynch in cases like mine...

Comment: @bonCodigo: although not 1-on-1 the same as your case, this video http://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/BUILD2011/TOOL-816T is still my favorite reference for the concepts and how it can help you achieve asynchronous UI updates.