# Adding User Control (WPF) to Panel in Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, outlook

I'm making an Outlook add in that when a user launches the add in, a windows form comes up. within this windows form, I will be dynamically adding user controls based on the user input.

The problem i'm having is adding the control programmatically. It all works fine if I just add a standard `TextBox` but when I add the user control, I get the below exception;

> **The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(System.Windows.Forms.Control)' has some invalid arguments**
>
> **cannot convert from 'OutlookAddIn.Controls.RForm' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'**

I tried casting the control to an `UserControl` but a new exceptions arose.

Main Form:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OutlookAddIn
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void lblReactiveMaintenance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OutlookAddIn.Controls.RForm reactiveMaintForm = new OutlookAddIn.Controls.RForm();
            reactiveMaintForm.Name = "rForm";
            pnlMain.Controls.Add(reactiveMaintForm);
        }
    }
}
```

User Control:

```
namespace OutlookAddIn.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for RForm.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class RForm : UserControl
    {
        public RForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put WPF control into a Windows Forms Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053501/put-wpf-control-into-a-windows-forms-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the ElementHost control to wrap the WPF control. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx.

```
private void lblReactiveMaintenance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OutlookAddIn.Controls.RForm = new OutlookAddIn.Controls.RForm();
    reactiveMaintForm.Name = "rForm";
    elementHost2.Child = reactiveMaintForm;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did try to use element host but I'm not sure if I have to configure the hosted content within in the designer or if I can throw in the element host control and just configure it pragmatically. I tried the URL mentioned in the comments above but the article seems to have been deleted. Do you have an example or a URL on how to programatically configure the hosted content of an element host