# How to add user control to tab control page and how to open entire tab control on button click using c# winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to add user control to tab control in winforms and how to open entire tab control panel on single button click?

Comment: Please post the code you tried so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053501/put-wpf-control-into-a-windows-forms-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Before the question was edited:*

Use `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.Elementhost`.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
// Create the ElementHost control to host the WPF UserControl.
ElementHost WPFHost = new ElementHost();
WPFHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

// Create the WPF UserControl.
HostingWpfUserControlInWf.UserControl1 uc = new HostingWpfUserControlInWf.UserControl1();

// Add the WPF UserControl to the Host.
WPFHost.Child = uc;

// Add the ElementHost to the form.
this.Controls.Add(WPFHost);
```

[Or you can use XAML to design Winform Project GUI](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/use-xaml-to-design-winform-75d73893)

Comment: Or, y'know, just Panel. Which is the common control to do stuff like that.

Comment: @Nyerguds You cannot make a `Panel` host WPF or use Xaml code.

Comment: @shad0wk Was that ever specified in the question? It's tagged winforms, not WPF.