# Display labels in horizontal tree [treeView] Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, tree, treeview, horizontallist

I am working now on the project for my client, which is something like Display Editor, where user can add display, write something in it etc... Every display is connected to another display, by that I mean, it has Parent, Left/Right Sibling and Child. Its practically linked list. And you can jump from one display to another with arrows keys Up, Left, Right and Down. All this is completely okay. My problem is, that client want something like **treeView**, but **horizontal**. Because when I use normal treeView, Display dont match with the arrows rules (Up,Left etc...), Its vice versa.

I was desperate so I created my own Control, where I am adding **Labels** and every time new **Node** is added I am changing Location of already exists Labels. Here are some images.
[Second child of "Right Sibling"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmF1E.jpg)
["Right Sibling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfMdA.jpg)

But as you can see, its not looking very nice and also its not very good for using. Also I cant figure how to delete there, because location changing when deleting something is too much complicated. I searched a lot and I saw like thousand articles, but everything useful is for WPF and I am using **Windows Forms**, that is the problem. I am afraid I will have to figure it out, but first I am calling for help. Thank you.

Comment: There seems to be only very little room in either direction; are the demads as limited? Also. A Teeview can expand and collapse; will you need that too? But writing a custom tree layout will, while possible, be not really simple and deletions are just of of many challenges there..

Comment: @TaW width can be limited for like 100-150 pixels, it doesnt need to have autosize, it can be "hardcoded". I dont need expand and collapse. Yeah I know its not very simple, thats why I am just looking for something very simple, where the tree only display "Name". Nothing more

Comment: if you have a [tag:wpf] control, you can embed it into a form using ElementHost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053501/put-wpf-control-into-a-windows-forms-form

Comment: @ASh Nice, this looks pretty good, I will try it. Thank you so much... I didnt know about this feature.