# wpf Snack bar not showing messages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dispatcher, material-design-in-xaml

I am using MaterialsDesigninXAML. When trying to use the snack bar with the MVVM method I ran into an issue that was preventing the Snackbar from displaying a message. I have included the ViewModel and the associated XAML code. I had a look through the [MaterialDesign Snackbar Wiki](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Snackbar) but was unable to see what I had missed.

*MainScreenViewModel*

```
private SnackbarMessageQueue m_messagequeue;

    public MainScreenViewModel()
    {
        MESSAGEQUEUE = new SnackbarMessageQueue(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(8000));

    }

    public SnackbarMessageQueue MESSAGEQUEUE { get { return m_messagequeue; }  set {m_messagequeue = value; OnPropertyChanged("MESSAGEQUEUE"); } }
    public void On_message_click()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MESSAGEQUEUE.Enqueue("Wow, easy!"));
    }
}
```

MainScreen.xaml

```
<Button Content="message" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}"
                                                     MethodName="On_message_click"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
<materialDesign:Snackbar MessageQueue="{Binding MESSAGEQUEUE}"  />
```

But when running I noticed the issue that the Dispatcher cant finds the snack bar. I am wondering why this is or if I am missing something to get the messages to appear on the snack bar.

```
//find a target
var snackbar = await FindSnackbar(exemplar.Dispatcher);

    //show message
if (snackbar != null){...}
```

Comment: Two thoughts. 
1. In your On_message_click, use your debugger and examine the private field `_pairedSnackbars` of the `MESSAGEQUEUE`. If the pairing has occurred successfully you should see a single item in there.
2. Check your output window after calling `Enqueue`. Do you see the message "A snackbar message as waiting, but no Snackbar instances are assigned to the message queue."?

Comment: @KevinB _pairedSnackbars = 1 so thats good and I dont see that message in the output. I did originally but realised that the Snackbar hadnt been created before messages were being assigned to it. just a thought, I have created a usercontrol which is hosted in a window would that cause an issue for FindSnackbar's Window = getwindow(sb) ? (sorry currently limited knowledge of dispatchers)

Comment: The Dispatcher is just a way to execute code on the UI thread. This is required since it is interacting with UI elements. Is the top level parent of the snackbar hosted in a normal WPF window (is there any interop with something like WinForms in the view hierarchy?)

Comment: I host the WPF user control containing the Snackbar using an ElementHost within a Winform.  Similar to this:  [StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5053543/5531211)

Comment: Ah then yes that will be the reason it is not working. Because of this check in `FindSnackbar`: `return window != null && window.WindowState != WindowState.Minimized;`. This looks like something that could be easily fixed. I would open a new issue on the repo.

Comment: I have same issue. Using Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MESSAGEQUEUE.Enqueue("Wow, easy!")); or just MESSAGEQUEUE.Enqueue("Wow, easy!"); I got same results, sometimes message is displayed and sometimes it is not. But, using the first approach the mesage "A snackbar message as waiting, but no Snackbar instances are assigned to the message queue." is shown. Why you use the first approach and why this message is displayed? I still use the second approach, which works much better.