# How to make UI page navigation in Office Word VSTO Add-in?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office, vsto

I'm on the beginning steps of creating a VSTO Word Add-in with `C#` which will reside inside a "Task Pane".

So my question revolves around the best way to make UI navigation. At the moment, I have created one `User Control` named "RegisterControl" and there is a form for registration. What I want to achieve is that after the user clicks "Register", the page should change to another "page" which is like the main page and has a different set of elements.

What is the way to go here? Creating multiple `User Control`s and switching their visibility on and off? (Very Ugly!)

Current code for ThisAddIn_Startup:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterControl registerControl = new RegisterControl();
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane CustomPaneHandler = CustomTaskPanes.Add(registerControl, "Task Pane Add-in");
    CustomPaneHandler.Visible = true;
}
```

Is there something more reliable instead of `User Control` for designing the UI? Maybe something like HTML and hopefully a bit of CSS?

P.S.: I have searched for a good amount of time for an answer and have come across things like `Data Template` and `WPF`, but none of them seem to be usable while developing VSTO/COM Word Add-ins. Any help or even pointers is much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use HTML and CSS for the taskpane why not an Office JS add-in?

Comment: FYI, you can put WPF into a task pane with an ElementHost. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053501/put-wpf-control-into-a-windows-forms-form

Comment: @CindyMeister You're right but the problem is that OfficeJS is only useful from API set version 1.3 onward and currently that version can only be found in Office 365; we are developing the add-in for Office 2016 so we have no other choice but VSTO.

Comment: @Chris Thanks a lot. Actually I've just found out about it. There should be a `User Control` to initialize the add-in and then WPF can sit inside that user control for the rest of the job. If you'd post this solution as an answer, I'd happily mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to answer your question, but that technically makes it a duplicate, so I'm going to mark it as such.